# "KeyError: 0" when calculating area of polygon using GeoPandas

Tags: polygon, geojson, geopandas, area, keyerror

I am working in Jupyter Notebook and overlaying two GeoJSON files. One is **property,** the other is **council zones**.

I am selecting the property id's and then clipping the zones that lie within the extent

```py
 ITT_PROP_select = ITT_PROP.query("(PROPID == 40932672)")
 ITT_PROP_select
```

[image]

```py
 select = gpd.clip(ITT_Zone, ITT_PROP_select)
 select
```

[image]

However when using the code below, I am unable to add a new column and calculate the areas for each row.

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape

for i in range(len(select)):
    select.loc[i, 'area_m2'] = shape(select.loc[i,'geometry']).area
```

The code returns:

> KeyError: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to calculate area and store it as a new column (attribute) is:

```py
df["area"] = df.area
```

but you might see a useful warning:

> UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'area' are likely incorrect. Use `GeoSeries.to_crs()` to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.

You can also use [`geometry_area_perimeter`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.geometry_area_perimeter) from PyProj >= 2.3.0 to calculate the area in m²:

```py
import geopandas

df = geopandas.read_file("file.shp")
geod = df.crs.get_geod()
df["area_m2"] = df.geometry.apply(lambda g: abs(geod.geometry_area_perimeter(g)[0]))
```